# Changing content of draggable, while moving with .sortable() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

How to change content of draggable item in .sortable() method? 
I need something like this:

- List of items (shop-unit)
- Drag item to Cart
- While dragging to cart, change content of draggable (under cursor)
- Change it content to something else...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). Specifically at the `helper` and `stop` function.

With the `helper`you can specify your own custom function so that you're dragging whatever you want (under the cursor). And the `stop` function takes place once you stop dragging. So you can apply some logic to make the adjustments you need to.